# .jar file assets file lose

Tags: android, jar, aar

in a android library i `implementation files('src/baidu/libs/BaiduLBS_Android.jar')`,in this .jar file has a assets directory.
[.jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZqpK.png) There are some pictures inside,size is 2292kB. i build this module generate .aar file,[arr file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iONHI.png)in this .arr file .jar file become small(867kb),,assets directory  be lost. i need these asset file.What should I do?